# Wakanda Error when Running when running Android device

Tags: angularjs, wakanda

I have installed Wakanda Studio and  Server Community Edition on Windows 10 and I create a project with angular and ionic.  When I clic in button Run, with  Run Android Devices  checked,  I get this:

> [Environment] $
>   C:/Users/panao/OneDrive/Documentos/Wakanda/solutions/conocimientoefectivo/conocimientoefectivo/mobile
>   ionic platform list [Environment] WARN: ionic.project has been renamed
>   to ionic.config.json, please rename it. [Environment] Installed
>   platforms: android 5.2.2 Available platforms:  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3
>   (deprecated) blackberry10 ~3.8.0 browser ~4.1.0 firefoxos ~3.6.3 webos
>   ~3.7.0 windows ~4.4.0 wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)
>
> [Environment] $
>   C:/Users/panao/OneDrive/Documentos/Wakanda/solutions/conocimientoefectivo/conocimientoefectivo/mobile
>   ionic plugin list [Environment] WARN: ionic.project has been renamed
>   to ionic.config.json, please rename it. [Environment]
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1-dev "Whitelist"
>
> [Environment] $ adb devices [Environment] List of devices attached 
>   e390ead8  device
>
> [Environment] $
>   C:/Users/panao/OneDrive/Documentos/Wakanda/solutions/conocimientoefectivo/conocimientoefectivo/mobile
>   ionic run -slc -device android --target=e390ead8 [Environment] WARN:
>   ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
>   [Environment] âœ— You cannot run iOS unless you are on Mac OSX.

```
Error when Running when running Android device e390ead8
```

I have my android phone connect to computer and enabled to debugin USB,
I would like to know what  happends. I am trying Wakanda.

**Update**

Wakanda Studio Console.

> [Environment] wakanda-extension-mobile-console 1.1.0 [Environment] If
>   you need help click here to open the troubleshooting! [Environment]
>   Environment variable JAVA_HOME: Found - C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 [Environment] Environment variable
>   ANDROID_HOME: Found - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>   [Environment] Android SDK: Found - Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
>   Revision 84e3321d5db3-android  [Environment] Node: Found - v7.0.0
>   [Environment] Java SDK: Found - C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe [Environment] Apache Ant: Found
>   - Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016 [Environment] Cordova: Found - 6.3.1
>   [Environment] Ionic 2: Found - 2.1.0
>   Blockquote

Checking Android SDK:

> C:\Users\panao>adb version
>
> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
>   Revision 84e3321d5db3-android

Answer (score 1):

Did you have latest [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) installed?

I believe the message in your title: "You cannot run iOS unless you are on Mac OSX" is just a warning message signalling iOS simulator is not available on Windows 10. It should not effect running application on Android.

Comment: Hi  I have updated my question, yes I have installed Android SDK. Error when Running when running Android device e390ead8

Comment: Looks like Does ADB and Cordova are all up to date. Does "Run on Android Simulator" work for you?

Comment: Definitely I don't have tried Run on Android Simulator yet, only I tried with deviced connected. Regards!